# Handling mouse click on JavaFX ImageView has a strange effect

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, eventhandler

I have a display with many ImageViews, where pressing on one of them prints it's location. The problem is that only pressing on the upper half part of the image gets handled (the location is printed as desired), pressing on the other part does nothing.

```
coverImage.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {
        System.out.println("Tile pressed " + book.getTitle());
        event.consume();
    });
```

And I tried:

```
    coverImage.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Tile pressed " + book.getTitle());
            event.consume();
        }
    });
```

How to make it work when clicking anywhere on the image?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there's another ImageView below it, where PickOnBounds value was true, so pressing on the area just above it (where the previous image is present) is handled as pressing on this image...